# Inverse of a special symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

We have a special matrix and we would like to find close form or analytical formula for its inverse.
The matrix is symmetric and it has only first and last row elements, first and last column elements and main diagonal. I am wondering if there is a name for this matrix and how we can find the inverse of it?

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\mathbf{A} =\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}&a_{14}&...&a_{1n}\\%
a_{12}&a_{22}&0&0&...&a_{2n}\\%
a_{13}&0&a_{33}&0&...&a_{3n}\\%
a_{14}&0&0&a_{44}&...&a_{4n}\\%
...&...&...&...&...&...\\%
a_{1n}&a_{2n}&a_{3n}&a_{4n}&...&a_{nn}\\%
\end{bmatrix}
\end{split}
\end{align}
This matrix can can also be considered as a sum of a diagonal matrix and a upper triangular matrix and its transpose :
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{labmda}+\mathbf{A_{u}}+\mathbf{A_{u}}^{T}
\end{split}
\end{align}
where

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\mathbf{labmda} =\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}&0&0&0&...&0\\%
0&a_{22}&0&0&...&0\\%
0&0&a_{33}&0&...&0\\%
0&0&0&a_{44}&...&0\\%
...&...&...&...&...&...\\%
0&0&0&0&...&a_{nn}\\%
\end{bmatrix}
\end{split}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\mathbf{A_{u}} =\begin{bmatrix}
0&a_{12}&a_{13}&a_{14}&...&a_{1n}\\%
0&0&0&0&...&a_{2n}\\%
0&0&0&0&...&a_{3n}\\%
0&0&0&0&...&a_{4n}\\%
...&...&...&...&...&...\\%
0&0&0&0&...&0\\%
\end{bmatrix}
\end{split}
\end{align}

Comment: Google "arrowhead matrix".

Comment: It is sum of two arrowhead matrices. how to handle this?

Comment: If you permute the rows and columns according to $(1,2,\ldots,n-1,n) \to (2,3,\ldots,n,1)$, then it becomes a block-arrowhead matrix. You can then partition the matrix into 4 blocks: a diagonal $(n-2) \times (n-2)$ matrix, a $(n-2) \times 2$ matrix, a $2 \times (n-2)$ matrix, and a $2 \times 2$ matrix. Then, you can apply the [block matrix inverse formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_inversion). After that, you can undo the permutation.

Comment: permutation of the rows and columns according to (1,2,…,n−1,n)→(2,3,…,n,1) won't make the top left part a diagonal matrix, since we have still the first column elements.

Comment: How about thinking of a block matrix with an arrowhead block, a row vector block, a column vector block and a scalar block?

Comment: Good idea @RodrigodeAzevedo, Any idea on inverse of such a matrix?

Comment: Inverting block matrices and arrowhead matrices should be well-studied questions.